# Change Widget on Dropdown onchange event

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with several options. For sake of simplicity lets say they are: "A", "B" and "C".

This is the snippet of my code:

```
children: <Widget>[
                      FormBuilder(
                        key: _fbKey,
                        autovalidate: true,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FormBuilderDropdown(
                              attribute: "value",
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Choose something?"),
                              hint: Text('Select Option'),
                              validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                              items: user.option.map((v) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: v,
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Image.asset(
                                        'assets/img/image.png',
                                        width: 50,
                                        height: 50,
                                      ),
                                      title: Text("${v.option}"),
                                    ));

                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                       // if v.option == "A" is selected here build Widget A()
                       // if v.option == "B" is selected here build Widget B()
                       // if v.option == "C" is selected here build Widget C()
                      ),
```

So, based on Dropdown selection I want to render appropriate Widget.
How can I build widget A if A is selected in the Dropdown menu, B if B is selected or C if C is selected?

This has to change dynamically though, any help is good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most simple way I see it is to create a function that renders your widgets, let's call it `_renderWidget()`, inside of that function you could have something as follows:

```
_renderWidget() {
 if(condition == A) {
  return Text('Widget A'); // this could be any Widget
 } else if(condition == B) {
  return Text('Widget B');
 } else {
  return Text('Widget C');
 }
}
```

Then inside your `DropdownButton` `onChanged` function, you can change the condition based on the dropdown value:

```
onChanged(String value) {

  if(value == 'something') {
    setState(() {
     condition = A; // A, B or C
    });  
  }

}
```

You would call your `_renderWidget()` function inside the widget where you want to show them, for example let's say a `Container` widget.

```
Container(
  child: _renderWidget()
)
```

Of course, all of this needs to be done inside a `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: Can you share with me the complete code for the above sample code?. Or any Github link to look for. I want to have a dropdown to display certain containers on dropdown change. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

use a [stateful widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=8&t=1s). you can have a field that says wich widget to show and call set state every time a different option is selected. all three widgets could be added to the main `List<Widget>` using [collection if](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d) as follows:

```dart
children: <Widget>[
                      FormBuilder(
                        key: _fbKey,
                        autovalidate: true,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FormBuilderDropdown(
                              attribute: "value",
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Choose something?"),
                              hint: Text('Select Option'),
                              validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                              items: user.option.map((v) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: v,
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Image.asset(
                                        'assets/img/image.png',
                                        width: 50,
                                        height: 50,
                                      ),
                                      title: Text("${v.option}"),
                                    ));

                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        ),
                       if (v.option == "A") A(),
                       if (v.option == "B") B(),
                       if (v.option == "C") C(),
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a widget that accept the option in its constructor, and call it under the Drop Down builder

Example :

```
    class RenderOption extends StatelessWidget {
  final option;

  const RenderOption({Key key, this.option}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (option) {
      case 1:
        return Container();
        break;
      case 2:
        return Container();
        break;
      case 3:
        return Container();
        break;

      default:
    }
  }
}
```

now in you code above

```
children: <Widget>[
                  FormBuilder(
                    key: _fbKey,
                    autovalidate: true,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FormBuilderDropdown(
                          attribute: "value",
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Choose something?"),
                          hint: Text('Select Option'),
                          validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                          items: user.option.map((v) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: v,
                                child: ListTile(
                                  leading: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/img/image.png',
                                    width: 50,
                                    height: 50,
                                  ),
                                  title: Text("${v.option}"),
                                ));

                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                   //_currentOption is declared above in the widget tree
                   // it indicates the current selected option
                   RenderOption(option:_currentOption)
                 ),
```

**Note** : you have to make the Parent Widget (which has the column or the listView as a child  ) Stateful widget to make the code run properly

**Edit** : I've added the *_currentOption* variable which indicated the current selected option and paste it to the **RenderOption** Widget. you should implement the `onChanged` function in the FormBuilderDropDown to update the selected option , like this

```
onChanged: (option) =>setState(()=>_currentOption = option)
```

Comment: But here v.option is out of scope. I mean in RenderOption constructor.